# Android title bar custom view does not stretch

Tags: android, android-actionbar, titlebar

I use api 21 titlebar in my app. I want to stretch my button or Linearlayout on it, but I can't. 
my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.toolbartest.MainActivity" >
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#ff9900"> 
<Button
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:text="GSSGSDGSDG"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>![enter image description here][1]


Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

I got this:

[image]

Comment: might help to turn on "show layout bounds" in developer settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, here xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:plugshare="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff9900"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app1:contentInsetStart="0dp" >

 <Button
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:text="GGSSSDFSDFSFFSDF" /> 
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```